# Countif offset formula comparing 2 values in same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Need help with a formula that will count a value only if it's 3 rows below a different value. Both values are in Column c. Example.  "Value1" is listed 5 times. So I have a countif for a total of 5.  2 times it is 3 rows below "value2".  I want a formula that will count  "value1" only if it's 3 rows below "value2".  So my formula would generate "2". I have a offset countif but I cannot get it to condition based on "value2"

Comment: Please show some test data and expected outcome, it is easier to understand than simple text explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stagger (i.e. offset) the various criteria_range(s) of a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED). It is important that the ranges are the same size and shape; it not important that they are exactly the same rows or columns.

```
=COUNTIFS(C1:C99, "value2", C4:C102, "value1")
```

Note that C4:C102 (*criteria_range2* for *value1*) is still 99 rows but offset 3 rows from C1:C99 (*criteria_range1* for *value2*).

[image: countifs_stagger]

Comment: Thank you for the imput! I will try this tonight and see if it works for me!!